# Unity - Make Timed Power Up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

can you help me to make timed powerup that will effect for certain time

here is my code

```
public int jumpTrig = 0;
public int speed = 0;
public int health = 0;

public float duration = 0;
public float timer = 0;
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coli)
{
    if (coli.gameObject.tag == "Player")

    {
        coli.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().jumpForce += jumpTrig;
        coli.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().speed += speed;
        coli.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().health += health;

        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually **not recommend** to use a **timer in `Update`** here because it hinders you to already at least deactivate the according `GameObject`. The same also applies to a **Corotuine**.

In both cases you can not `Destroy` or `SetActive(false)` the PowerUp item which would bother me.

---

But you can use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) for this!

Afaik it still breaks if the object gets destroyed **but** it works on an inactive GameObject!

So instead disable it first and `Destroy` it later.

Some more points:

- In general you should use `GetComponent` as little as possible since it is quite expensive. Rather store the reference and reuse it.
- And you should rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) instead of using `==` directly. `CompareTag` is (very slightly) faster but the more important point: It throws an exception if the provided Tag is e.g. spelled wrong/doesn't exist. The `==` hides such a "bug" and rather simply fails which can cost you some development time and nerves ;)
- Note that I would also give your fields better names

So your code might look like

```
public int jumpBonus = 0;
public int speedBonus = 0;
public int healthBonus = 0;

public float duration = 0;

private PlayerMove playerMove;
private Health playerHealth;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coli)
{
    if (!coli.CompareTag("Player")) return;

    playerMove = coli.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMove>();
    playerHealth = coli.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>();

    playerMove.jumpForce += jumpBonus;
    playerMove.speed += speedBonus;
    playerHealth.health += healthBonus;

    gameObject.SetActive(false);

    // Calls ResetEffect after "duration" seconds even if gameObject is inactive
    Invoke(nameof(ResetEffect), duration);
}

private void ResetEffect()
{
    playerMove.jumpForce -= jumpBonus;
    playerMove.speed -= speedBonus;
    playerHealth.health -= healthBonus;

    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, the output like that i expected

Answer (score 0):

You can do a single timer using Update and DeltaTime to work over a float of your desired time.

```
public float powerTime = 0.0f
private bool poweredUp = false;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coli)
{
    if (coli.gameObject.tag == "Player")

    {
        powerTime = 10.0f;
    }

}

Update()
{ 
    powerTime -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (powerTime > 0.0f && !poweredUp)
    {
        poweredUp = true;
        doPowerUp();
    }
    else if (poweredUp)
    {
        doPowerEnd()
    }

void doPowerUp()
{
    coli.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().jumpForce += jumpTrig;
    coli.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().speed += speed;
    coli.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().health += health;


}

void doPowerEnd()
{
    poweredUp = false;
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
//reset to your normal values.
}
```

Comment: Now after your update there is still another issue: The PowerUp stays visible for 10 seconds even though it was used already ;) Also since `powerTime = 0f` at the beginning it will immeditiately jump into `doPowerEnd` in the first frame ;)